# HELP ~ Removed permission accidentally - lost list

Tags: permissions

I created a master page to house several links to other pages with content.  I tried to remove the permissions from one of the "sub- pages" and accidentally removed from the master page.  I was able to restore the permissions  for the page.  However, I had a list also included in the master page and this is now telling me I don't have permission to access the list.  I am set up with full control on the page.  Can someone please help, I don't want to have to recreate this list!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to log in as a site collection administrator, that security level has permission to everything everywhere. As a site owner, you can lock yourself out of lists, but site collection administrators cannot (unless they remove themselves from the site collection administrator permission)

Answer (score 0):

Log on with a site collection administrator account (there is at least one always) and you will be able to access all the content on the site collection.